# Which is the best blockchain framework if I want to develop the DApp for myself?

Tags: blockchain

I am a beginner of Blockchain development, and I have master Java and C# which I use for my Android and ASP.NET MVC programs. Recently, I start to learn how to develop Blockchain application, and I find there are many frameworks for this technology, such as Ethereum, Lisk and so on. My question is which framework should I learn if I want to develop the DApp for myself and I expect it will be a commercial product in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few frameworks to choose from.  Consider 1st if you want your dapp to be public or private.  Private might point to [Hyperledger](https://www.hyperledger.org/projects) in that case you'd use Burrow if you went with a public implementation you'd most likely use solidity on the Ethereum network.  [blockcerts](https://github.com/blockchain-certificates) and [edx](https://www.edx.org/course/blockchain-business-introduction-linuxfoundationx-lfs171x) are excellent resources to learn more with hands on examples.